# Using pyqgis logic to stop process if output has no geometry

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a pyqgis script which customises the functionality of the grass algorithm r.lake.coords:

```
##Seed Points Lake=name
##DEM_input=raster
##Seed_vector_points=vector point
##Overspill_vector_boundary=vector polygon
##output=folder


# Import classes
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
import processing

# Define layers
point_layer = processing.getObject(Seed_vector_points)
layer = processing.getObject(DEM_input)
boundary_layer = processing.getObject(Overspill_vector_boundary)
fileName = layer.source()
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)

# Get extent of the region
extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

for feat in point_layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feat.geometry()
    attr = feat.attribute("Z_ADD_1")
    i = 0
    while i < 5: 
        output_1 = processing.runalg('grass:r.lake.coords', layer, "%f"%(attr), "%f,%f"% (geom.asPoint().x(), geom.asPoint().y()) , False, "%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), 0.00, None)
        output_2 = processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', output_1['lake'], '','a>0', False, 3, None)
        output_3 = processing.runalg('gdalogr:polygonize', output_2['RESULT'], "DN", None)
        output_4 = processing.runalg('qgis:dissolve',output_3['OUTPUT'], True, "DN", None)
        output_5 = processing.runalg("qgis:extractbylocation", output_4['OUTPUT'], boundary_layer, u'within', output + '/' + baseName + "_%.6f_%.6f" %(geom.asPoint().x(), geom.asPoint().y()) + "_%.2f"%(attr) + 'm.shp')
        i += 1
        attr += 0.5
```

My problem is that the final algorithm which the script calls upon produces additional blank shapefiles where there is no geometry, this is technically correct if the outputs from output_4 are not within the overspill boundary.

However, I would ideally like to have the script set up using some sort of python logic where it avoids producing final shapefiles with no geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great answer by [@LaughU](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/81214/laughu)! If you want to prevent processed layers with no geometry to have no output, you could use the `None` parameter to save the output as a temporary file initially, check if this has any features and if so, write to a shapefile otherwise skip it:

```
...
output_5 = processing.runalg("qgis:extractbylocation", output_4['OUTPUT'], boundary_layer, u'within', 0.00, None)
layer = processing.getObject(output_5['OUTPUT'])
if not layer.featureCount() == 0:
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output + '/' + baseName + "_%.6f_%.6f" %(geom.asPoint().x(), geom.asPoint().y()) + "_%.2f"%(attr) + 'm.shp', "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
    i += 1
    attr += 0.5
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, it seems to be working fine for a single iteration (I assume) as I get one output and then I get the error message "'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' See log for more details". Having tested this out manually, I should be getting two valid results.

Comment: In the console the same error is "Error: Wrong parameter value: <qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x155228A0>"

Comment: @Ian - Apologies, I missed the precision parameter in the algorithm. This should avoid the wrong parameter error atleast. Also, are you sure `i = 0` should not be outside the loop? Because it is resetting to 0 for every feature.

Answer (score 5):

I prevent empty layers from loading with this code snippet:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
if not self.layer.isValid():
   iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Info:", "Layer not valide", level=QgsMessageBar.WARNING)
   pass
elif layer.featureCount() == 0:
   pass 
elif layer.featureCount() != 0:
   print "do something usefull here"
   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

In your use case, you would iterate over the 5 outputs and and check if the layer is empty and then load the layers with  `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)` into QGIS

Comment: Great code for preventing the loading of null geometries into QGIS @LaughU, I'll certainly be using this in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Having used both of your excellent answers, I have come up with the following solution which works perfectly:

```
##Seed Points Lake=name
##DEM_input=raster
##Seed_vector_points=vector point
##Overspill_vector_boundary=vector polygon
##output=folder


# Import classes
from qgis.core import (QgsRasterLayer, QgsVectorFileWriter)
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
import processing

# Define layers
point_layer = processing.getObject(Seed_vector_points)
layer = processing.getObject(DEM_input)
boundary_layer = processing.getObject(Overspill_vector_boundary)
fileName = layer.source()
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)


# Get extent of the region
extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

for feat in point_layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feat.geometry()
    attr = feat.attribute("Z_ADD_1")
    i = 0
    while i < 5: 
        output_1 = processing.runalg('grass:r.lake.coords', layer, "%f"%(attr), "%f,%f"% (geom.asPoint().x(), geom.asPoint().y()) , False, "%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), 0.00, None)
        output_2 = processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', output_1['lake'], '','a>0', False, 3, None)
        output_3 = processing.runalg('gdalogr:polygonize', output_2['RESULT'], "DN", None)
        output_4 = processing.runalg('qgis:dissolve',output_3['OUTPUT'], True, "DN", None)
        output_5 = processing.runalg("qgis:extractbylocation", output_4['OUTPUT'], boundary_layer, u'within', None)
        layer_1 = processing.getObject(output_5['OUTPUT'])
        if not layer_1.featureCount() == 0:
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer_1, output + '/' + baseName + "_%.6f_%.6f" %(geom.asPoint().x(), geom.asPoint().y()) + "_%.2f"%(attr) + 'm.shp', "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
        else:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Info:", "Process Complete :)", level=QgsMessageBar.SUCCESS)
        i += 1
        attr += 0.5
```

Thanks again for the solutions guys, much appreciated.